# Oauth error invalid_request: The redirect_uri is not whitelisted With nodejs api

Tags: node.js, reactjs, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api-node

I want to use shopify api libary and want to perform 0Auth but I got following error:

```
Oauth error invalid_request: The redirect_uri is not whitelisted
```

I set the api keys correctly and also the whitelist at app setup
[image]

Code:

```
const shopify = shopifyApi({
  apiKey: 'xxx',
  apiSecretKey: 'xxxx',
  scopes: ['read_products'],
  hostName: 'https://71c7-2a02-908-4b41-18c0-c5de-7a54-ea2f-9096.ngrok-free.app/',
  apiVersion: LATEST_API_VERSION,
  isEmbeddedApp: true
});

app.get('/auth', async (req: any, res: any) => {
  try {
    // The library will automatically redirect the user
    await shopify.auth.begin({
      shop: shopify.utils.sanitizeShop(req.query.shop, true),
      callbackPath: '/auth/callback',
      isOnline: false,
      rawRequest: req,
      rawResponse: res,
    });
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.send(e);
  }
});

app.get('/auth/callback', async (req: any, res: any) => {
  // The library will automatically redirect the user
  console.log('CALLBACK');
  const callback = await shopify.auth.callback({
    rawRequest: req,
    rawResponse: res,
  });
  
  console.log(callback);

  res.send('AUTH');
});
```

Comment: This happens for a couple of reasons 
1. Add "/auth" path in the redirected url's of the app 
2. Just make sure to that the apiKey is same as app api key